# Find all instances of a specific day of the week between two dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find all instances of a day of a week between two given dates. The day of the week can change. I've seen a similar question posted on here, but it doesn't seem to work for variables

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
DECLARE @earliestStartDate DATETIME = '2016-08-01 00:00:00.000';
DECLARE @latestStartDate DATETIME = '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000';
DECLARE @weeklyCoursesStartDay INT = 1;
DECLARE @maxCourses INT = 30;

CREATE TABLE #Dates(CourseDate DATETIME);

    WITH CTE(dt)
    AS
            (SELECT @earliestStartDate
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DATEADD(day, @weeklyCoursesStartDay, dt) FROM CTE--SELECT DATEADD(day, @weeklyCoursesStartDay, dt) FROM CTE
             WHERE dt < @latestStartDate)

             INSERT INTO #Dates(CourseDate) 
             SELECT TOP(@maxCourses) dt 
             FROM CTE  
             WHERE DATEPART(DW, dt) = @weeklyCoursesStartDay
             OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

             SELECT * FROM #Dates
             DROP TABLE #Dates
```

This returns the below, as expected.

2016-08-01 00:00:00.000 
2016-08-08 00:00:00.000 
2016-08-15 00:00:00.000 
2016-08-22 00:00:00.000 
2016-08-29 00:00:00.000 
2016-09-05 00:00:00.000 
2016-09-12 00:00:00.000 
2016-09-19 00:00:00.000 
2016-09-26 00:00:00.000

But when the @weeklyCourseStartDay is changed to say, 5 (indicating a friday) it only returns two results:

2016-08-26 00:00:00.000 
2016-09-30 00:00:00.000

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific SQL there...)

Comment: I'm using SSMS 2014 on Azure SQL Server

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected result

Comment: Could you show the complete recursive SQL? And some sample input and expected output would be nice.

Comment: change `DATEADD(day, @weeklyCoursesStartDay, dt)` to `DATEADD(day, 1, dt)` because it should be add day by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, @weeklyCoursesStartDay, dt) FROM CTE
```

should actually be:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, dt) FROM CTE
```

This means that the recursive CTE will generate *every day* between `@earliestStartDate` and `@latestStartDate`, and, at a later stage, the `WHERE DATEPART(DW, dt) = @weeklyCoursesStartDay` clause will make sure only the days with the correct week day will remain.